# Позиционирование элементов вокруг окружности

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть задача:

> Расположить элементы вокруг окружности, чтобы они влияли друг на друга, т.е. если мы наводим на элемент, другие разъезжаются в сторону.

#### Требуемая структура:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
   <div class="item">
</div>
```

[image: дефолтное состояние][image: при наведении]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Что есть в интернете?

1. Позиционирование элементов по градусам (**не наш случай**) - https://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/vEJXGm
2. Равномерное распределение по всей длине окружности. Вариант интересный, но нет зависимостей от размера элементов - https://codepen.io/pat_hg/pen/JYEZMe?limit=all&page=3&q=circle
3. Свойство `shape-outside`, работает только с текстом (**совсем не то**) - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

### Как реализовать?

1. Определяем угол сектора, который займет наш элемент. Я делал расчеты по хорде, хорду тоже нужно вычислить, т.к. взять просто `радиус * 2` не получится - будут расхождения между элементами.
2. Суммируем углы до центра элемента
3. Вычисляем точку на окружности и назначаем координаты элементу

**Теперь нужно вычислять углы, когда мы взаимодействуем с элементом:**

4. При наведении, можно менять все, что угодно, но главную роль для нас играют **размеры**. Записываем новые размеры в буфер или в атрибут элемента и делаем перерасчет позиций
5. Окей, углы для изменившихся элементов высчитываются по старым формулам, они соответственно, стали больше, и элементы сдвинулись вправо.
6. Но если нужно, чтобы элементы сдвигались по обе стороны, то необходимо записывать в буфер предыдущее (начальное) значение размеров, далее вычисляем разность и убавляем угол каждого элемента на половину угла изменившегося элемента.

### Работающий код с комментариями:

```js
var container = $('.container');
var radius = $('.container').height() / 2;
var item = $('.item');

var leftAngle = 0;

//start angle
var angle = -Math.PI / 2; // 90 deg

//angle steps between elements
var step = Math.PI / 12; //15 deg

var multiplier = 1;

function calcPositions() {
  //calculate left rotation angle 
  item.each(function() {
    //difference in sizes if item hovered
    var sizesDiff = $(this).attr('data-width') - $(this).attr('data-before');
  
    //if sizes are different, calc angle to rotate items to left
    if(sizesDiff != 0 && leftAngle == 0) {
      leftAngle = angleByChord($(this).attr('data-width') / 2, radius) / 4;
    }
  });
  
  //rotate items to left
  if(leftAngle != 0) {
    angle -= leftAngle;
  }
  
  leftAngle = 0;
  
  item.each(function(index) {
    
    //if first, no rotation
    if(index == 0) {
      multiplier = 0;
    } else {
      multiplier = 1;
    }
    
    //get container circle section angle
    var thisItemAngleSection = angleByChord($(this).attr('data-width') / 2, radius);
    
    //this aitem angle rotation
    angle += ((thisItemAngleSection / 2) + step) * multiplier;
    
    //calculate positions
    var posX = radius + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    var posY = radius + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    
    //set half of angle to next element
    multiplier = 1
    angle += ((thisItemAngleSection / 2) + step) * multiplier;
    
    $(this).css({
      left: posX + 'px',
      top: posY + 'px'
    });
  });
  
  //reset
  angle = -Math.PI / 2;
}

//get angle of item 
function angleByChord(this_radius, radius) {
  var a = (2*radius*radius - this_radius*this_radius) / (2 * radius);
  
  var chord = Math.sqrt(radius*radius - a*a) * 2;
  
  return Math.asin(chord / (2 * radius)) * 2;
}

/*  actions  */
$('.start').on('click', function() {
  calcPositions();
});

$('.item').hover(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-before', $(this).width());
  $(this).addClass('big');
  
  //update final widths (after transitions)
  $(this).attr('data-width', getFinalWidthOfElement($(this)));
  
  //recalsulate positions
  calcPositions();
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('big');
  
  //return widths
  $(this).attr('data-width', 30);//getFinalWidthOfElement($(this)));
  $(this).attr('data-before', 30);//$(this).width());
  
  calcPositions();
  
  leftAngle = 0;
});

function getFinalWidthOfElement(element) {

  //clone current elem
  var clone = element.clone();
  
  //remove transitions to get final sizes
  clone.css('transition', 'none');

  //hide and change classes
  clone.hide();
  clone.removeClass('item');

  element.parent().append(clone);
  
  //our final sizes of item
  var endHeight = clone.height();

  //remove because we're already get sizes
  clone.remove();

  return endHeight;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.big {
  background: orange;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.start {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #cccc;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="start">Start</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-width="30" data-before="30">1</div>
  <div class="item" data-width="30" data-before="30">2</div>
  <div class="item" data-width="30" data-before="30">3</div>
  <div class="item" data-width="30" data-before="30">4</div>
  <div class="item" data-width="30" data-before="30">5</div>
</div>
```

Для доработок: https://codepen.io/meetromb/pen/LdXgNd

Answer (score 0):

Конечно это совсем не меню но просто получилось вот так сделать но можно доработать и будет то что надо :

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:all .5s .3s cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.81, 0.58, 0.01);
}

.items{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:80px auto;
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#fbfbfb;
}
.cord,
.item{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:2px;
  height:2px;
  background:#ccc;
  margin:-1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.items:hover .cord{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:calc(100% - 50px);
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
}

.items:hover .item1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:calc(85% - 50px);
  top:calc(15% - 50px); 
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-delay:0.1s;
}
.items:hover .item2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:90px;
  top:-40px;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay:0.2s;
}
.items:hover .item3{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:-20px;
  top:5px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay:0.3s;
}

.items:hover .item4{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:-45px;
  top:115px;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay:0.4s;
}

.items:hover .item5{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:25px;
  top:215px;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay:0.5s;
}
.item{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
.items:hover .cords,
.items:hover .item{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  animation:scale .5s  .3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.92, 0.11);
}

@keyframes scale{
  100%{
transform:scale(.3)rotate(360deg);  
background:#fbfbfb;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
  <div class="cord"></div>
</div>
```